# Would the Earth still precess if it were an ideal sphere?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, planet, tides

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to acquire an intuitive understanding of planetary precession.

Is Earth’s precession **Torque-free Precession** due to its asymmetry as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precession ?

> If an object is *asymmetric about its principal axis of rotation*, the
> moment of inertia with respect to each coordinate direction will
> change with time, while preserving angular momentum.

If Earth's precession is Torque-free, presumably precession would not occur if the Earth were an ideal sphere.

The alternative is that Earth’s precession is **Torque-Induced Precession** . I’m not clear on how the Sun imposes a torque on a sphere, spinning or not. If it is imposing tidal forces due to Earth's oblate spheroid shape, these tidal forces would disappear if the Earth were an ideal sphere.

So an ideal sphere would not process from either Torque-free or Torque-induced precession. Is that right?

**Edit** This question was cross-posted to Astronomy and an accepted answer was "no, earth would not precess if it were an ideal sphere". This post will be deleted in 2 days.

Comment: An ideal sphere doesn't precess. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/426956/207316 But a rotating sphere (that isn't infinitely rigid) must be flattened.

Comment: @PM2Ring unfortunately, the video link in the MathSE answer is dead, so I couldn't follow the explanation. Could you please submit an answer to the OP?

Comment: Seems like the question is better suited to physics SE. It doesn't matter if you name a perfect sphere Earth, it won't have a relation to real astronomy.

Comment: @GregMiller... good point. Because precession affects satellite orbits, I thought there may be some interest and insights here on SE.

Comment: A perfect rotating sphere is impossible anyway, only a rotating ellipsoid could be (theoretically) perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If the question was "Is the portion of the Earth's precession (that is, change in the orientation of the rotational axis) attributable to the mechanism of "torque-free precession" significant?" then it would be harder to answer this question. But it would be one of those questions where I would trust my gut -  and my gut says, "No, it would not be in the least bit significant.".

Perhaps I'm stating the obvious here, but if the Earth was an ideal sphere, and it still had oceans on it, then it would still have tides. It would still lose energy due to tidal friction. Then it would precess due to torque-induced friction. If it was an undeformable perfect sphere with no oceans or atmosphere to slosh around, then I can think of no way for it to experience torque due to, for example, gravitational influence (other than the possible exception explained below). My understanding is that without torque, a perfect sphere will not precess according to [Newtonian Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_dynamics).

Of course, there are subtle effects such as the [YORP effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YORP_effect) that might still be able to generate a tiny amount of torque. The Earth gets continually bombarded by asteroids as well.

There are also two relativistic effects called [Lense–Thirring precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession) and [Geodetic Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_effect) (also known as geodetic precession, de Sitter precession or the de Sitter effect). These manifest as a daisy-petal effect as the orbital perihelion precesses.

[image]

I think this type of precession is outside the scope of your question; however, if I understand the Wikipedia article correctly, the [Lense–Thirring precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession) will cause rotational axis precession to occur.

That said, a disclaimer - I don't understand relativity well enough to confidently explain when and how relativistic effects cause rotational axis precession to occur. That might be a good question for Stack Exchange Physics! Also, on the Physics site, you can learn more about the relativistic effects from [these answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26408/what-did-general-relativity-clarify-about-mercury).

Comment: +1! I like the YORP-induced torque and relativistic *orbital* precession very much! Also, "torque" is mentioned in Wikipedia's [Frame-dragging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging) and it goes on to link to [Lense–Thirring precession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lense%E2%80%93Thirring_precession). You might add those back into your answer post and I can delete this comment. However, I think having surface ocean tidal highs and lows breaks the "perfect sphere" stipulation, as would density/salinity tides in a subsurface ocean.